# How to get sum of points along curve?

Tags: math

```
startingQuantity / numberAvailable = price

5 apples / 4 available = $1.25
```

So if there are 4 available and the price is 1.25 and someone buys three apples then they would pay 1.25 +  1.666 + 2.5 = $5.416

What is the equation to get 5.416?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about arithmetic, and may be more appropriate on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

At last are looking for [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

```
(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+.....+(1/n)
```

There is no simple solution for it. You may have to use power series and complex integrals if you want an equation. So using simple code will be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

5/4 = 1.25

5/3 = 1.6666666666

5/2 = 2.5

Let use base 12 as an "equal base":

Therefore (15 + 20 + 30) / 12 =>

65 / 12 = 5.416

Comment: I'm looking for an equation that will work for larger numbers.  For example how would you figure it out if starting quantity was 1,000,000 and number available was 500,000 and someone wanted to buy 240,000?